# HTML Table adding space at the bottom of a row.

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have been using this table for a while now and all of a sudden its broken now. I have CSS in my files for it but for whatever reason its now adding a blank line to the bottom of the table row after the form image is posted. It does this even with this same table with no CSS. I have tried table height, spacing, the works. I cannot figure out why there is a blank line here. I apologize if it turns out to be a stupid fix I have searched and tried many fixes.

[HERE IS AN EXAMPLE](http://johndayers.com/t.html)

```
<table border="1">
      <tr>
        <td></td>

        <td>
          <form action="" method="post">
            <div>
              <input type="hidden" name="id" value="" />
              <input type="hidden" name="d" value="1" />
              <input type="image" src="../resources/img/direction/up_arrow.png" alt="Up" width="62" height="62" />
            </div>
          </form>
        </td>

        <td></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>
          <form action="" method="post">
            <div>
              <input type="hidden" name="id" value="" />
              <input type="hidden" name="d" value="2" />
              <input type="image" src="../resources/img/direction/left_arrow.png" alt="Left" width="62" height="62" />
            </div>
          </form>
        </td>

        <td>
          <form action="" method="post">
            <div>
              <input type="hidden" name="id" value="" />
              <input type="hidden" name="r" value="1" />
              <input type="image" src="../resources/img/direction/rest_button.png" alt="Rest" width="62" height="62" />
            </div>
          </form>
        </td>

        <td>
          <form action="" method="post">
            <div>
              <input type="hidden" name="id" value="" />
              <input type="hidden" name="d" value="3" />
              <input type="image" src="../resources/img/direction/right_arrow.png" alt="Right" width="62" height="62" />
            </div>
          </form>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td></td>

        <td>
          <form action="" method="post">
            <div>
              <input type="hidden" name="id" value="" />
              <input type="hidden" name="d" value="4" />
              <input type="image" src="../resources/img/direction/down_arrow.png" alt="Down" width="62" height="62" />
            </div>
          </form>
        </td>

        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Does your code break by itself or do you mean in a specific browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `form`s of the `td`s have a margin. Add following css:

```
form {
    margin: 0;
}
```

To prevent more of this behaviours you should include e.g. a [normalize.css](http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/) instead.

Comment: Thanks for the help i was pulling my hair out over it. I use that tip as well thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This css is what will solve your problem:

```
form {margin:0;padding:0}
```

The extra space was basically coming from your form. You probably removed some old code from css and that's why it suddenly broke.